# jQuery Mobile - preventDefault() on button (link)

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, event-handling, popup, preventdefault

I'm developing jQuery Mobile (jQm) app.

I wanna utilize taphold event to some crucial elements, such as *remove button*, to assure, that this element is secured from unwanted trigger.

I created Remove button on jQm popup and aded some JS to it, but I cannot force default action to quit, not with `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, nor with `return false`.

I prepared jsFiddle as duplicate of my code. The popup there contains simple progress bar as indicator of holded tap. You can try it here: **[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Bb7wj/10/)** *(note: HTML5 data tag `taphold="true"` is not jQm default)*

As a workaround, I'm currently replacing `<a href="#" data-role="button"...></a>` with `<div>`styled like button. This works well, since it doesn't have any default action, but I'm curious why the "proper" solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a:jqmData(taphold='true')").bind("vmousedown vmouseup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

The `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` used in the above piece of code, refer to the `vmousedown` and `vmouseup` events *and not to every event which is bound to the selected element(s)*.

This means that the default behaviour for the `click` event still exists. So when you click the remove button, the click event is triggered and that's why the pop up closes immediately.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple & stupid, as usual. Basicaly I just missed `click` in `vmousedown vmouseup click`. Thank you for this one.